# Samsung monitor looks blurry and has black borders when resolutions match

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, vga

I have had a Syncmaster S23B300 connected to my computer via VGA cable for about two years now and never had one problem.  However, recently I had to give away my VGA cable and temporarily switch to a different Samsung monitor (connected via HDMI).  When using this monitor the DPI was broken and the screen scaling didn't work so everything was huge.  Sadly, I could find no fix to this problem and had to live with it for a couple of weeks until I got a new VGA cable.  I have now got a new Polaroid VGA cable and reconnected my old monitor.  However, when I did reconnect it the scaling was fixed but the display was blurry, washed and sharp.  So i tried to do an auto-correction however, this did not fix the blur, sharpness and washey-ness(?) but just made a big black bar of unused screen on the right side of the monitor.  I fixxed the black bar by resting the monitors settings however even still parts of the screen are of the monitor and I think they were before.

I have been looking around and saw something about the resolutions not being set the same however, the monitor and Windows are both set to 1920*1080 the optimal for the monitor.

Examples of the blur:

[image: An example of the blur]

[image: An other example]

So I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix the these issues.  Any help is appreciated.

One thing to add is that when i got the new VGA cable out of its box it was held in a real by two bits of metal with plastic around them (you know what i mean) the plastic seemed to have melted and was attached to the VGA cable so when removing this caused slight damage to the cables insulation.

EDIT:

So I just looked at the linked image on a different device and it is perfect so the screen shot did not capture what i was seeing.

I recreated what the problem looks like for me in Photoshop:

[image]

Comment: Display scaling can be a nightmare, have you tried [disabling it](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html)? You can do this per display or per system.

Comment: I have tried most of the methods on that link when i was trying to make the new monitor work.  However, they did not fix it.

Comment: The images you linked to don't seem to have a problem to me. However, maybe you need to go to Settings->Display->Advanced display settings->ClearType text.

Comment: I may be seeing it because i'm using the computer with which has the problem but there are 4 or 5 faint outlines of the icon going to the left.

Comment: @Dan13_ Ahh... the echos of the signal suggest that the cable is faulty, or maybe the connections are a bit dirty.